# Scheduling algorithm

Tags: c#, scheduling

I want a certain job executed every 4 days starting from a start date and ending at an end date (or it can even never end). I could have different scheduling configurations, monthly, weekly, daily, even have daily recurrence like every 2 hours from 2 PM to 11 PM.

I'm looking for algorithms, code examples, etc.

Comment: What language? What system? Etc.

Comment: Do you want to implement this yourselves? Can you make use of Cron?

Comment: Yes we are implementing our OWN custom scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `cron` daemon fulfills this purpose on unix-derived platforms. You could take a look into [anacron's source code](http://anacron.sourceforge.net/) for details on a possible implementation of such a scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just setup your "job" to run using [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (Unix and Unix-like) or [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx) (Windows)?

This lets you setup schedules like you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) or [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: we did take a look at it, but we decided to implement our own.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a C# app running on Windows, the solution I typically use is to write a Console application and then schedule it using Windows Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need an "algorithm" for this. It sounds to me like you just want a general-purpose Date class.

Also, is this homework?